# How disable dates in jquery datetimepicker using "M-d-Y G:i" format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Currently I am using jQuery datetimepicker and I need to disable dates.

It does not work using the "M-d-Y" format. On the contrary, it works using the "d.m.y" format

here is my code

```
   $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            i18n: {
                en: {
                    months: [
                     'January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                     'may', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                     'September', 'october', 'November', 'December',
                    ],
                    dayOfWeek: [
                     "So.", "Mo", "Di", "Mi",
                     "Do", "Fr", "Sa.",
                    ]
                }
            },
            timepicker: true,
            format: 'M-d-Y G:i',
            disabledWeekDays: [0, 6],
            disabledDates: ['Aug-15-2018'], formatDate: 'M.d.Y'




        });
```

Comment: Try `m-d-Y`. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this [datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) plugin, you have a typo in this line:

```
formatDate: 'M.d.Y'
```

Change that line to:

```
formatDate: 'M.d.Y'
```

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    i18n: {
        en: {
            months: [
                'January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                'may', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                'September', 'october', 'November', 'December',
            ],
            dayOfWeek: [
                "So.", "Mo", "Di", "Mi",
                "Do", "Fr", "Sa.",
            ]
        }
    },
    timepicker: true,
    format: 'M-d-Y',
    disabledWeekDays: [0, 6],
    disabledDates: ['Aug.15.2018'],
    formatDate: 'M.d.Y'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<input class="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

Comment: if i change the format into 'M-d-Y G:i' then its not working